# Live streaming from ubuntu 12.10 amd64

Tags: 12.10, stream

I know that webcamstudio live exists still even though it is not developed anymore. I tried to install the .deb package on ubuntu 12.04 amd64. But gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse is missing from the repository.

So what I am asking is if there are any alternatives to webcamstudio which work on ubuntu 12.10 amd64?

Comment: Depends what you are tring to broadcast. If you are trying to broadcast your webcam, I reccomend ustream.tv but if you are trying to broadcast your desktop, I have searched & searched because i woul like to tke my podcasts live. But have not found anything that works well. You can dowload the missing dependency for webcamstudio here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/amd64/gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse/download

Comment: LinuxPCplus the capture software in ustream.tv does not allow capturing desktop. I want both desktop and webcam. I have searched and searched too. Software like this is something what Linux will need pretty soon, those Gamers will not move to Linux if they can not record their game play easily. Thanks for the dependancy. Will try to get webcamstudio to work.

Comment: Well let me warn you, i have never been able to get very good video quality with webcam studio. maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: Damn too many problems to solve with webcamstudio to run it on 12.10 amd64 I will give up and keep hunting for alternative. :/